XkbGetState - how to get exact modifier
According to the following thread I can get modifiers state using XkbGetState. Unfortunately XkbStateRec doesn't contain precise information, for example I would like to know which Shift key has been pressed - left or right. How to obtain such information ?

The state is logical, not physical. It represents modifiers in effect, not keys that are pressed. For the latter, you may need to track key press/key release events, or use XQueryKeymap (but I hear it doesn't work on XWayland, not sure).
